Confusion with cartans structure equation
I am trying to do some example calculations with the cartan structure equations to get an intuition for the Levi-Civita connection.
Suppose I consider for example a parabola. I can describe with polar coordinates, i.e
$$f\colon (r,\phi)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} r\cos(\phi) \\ r \sin(\phi) \\ r^2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then I can calculate the derivatives in $r$ and $\phi$ direction and get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) \\ 2r\end{pmatrix}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} = \begin{pmatrix} -r\sin(\phi)\\ r\cos(\phi)\\0\end{pmatrix}$.
Then the metric tensor is diagonal with
$$g = \mathrm{diag}(1 + 4 r^2, r^2),$$
thus I can pick as orthonormal frame field $e_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 4r^2}}\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) \\ 2r\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 4r^2}} f_\ast\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $e_1 = \frac{1}{r}\begin{pmatrix} -r\sin(\phi)\\ r\cos(\phi)\\0\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{r} f_\ast \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$.
Now, when I want to calculate the connection coefficients of the Levi-Civita using Cartans structure equations. I know that the resulting matrix $\omega$ has to be a skew symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix.
When I try to get the frame of dual 1-forms for this, I wanna express the 1-forms in terms of $dr$ and $d\phi$, which means that I have to express the vector fields in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$. This means here, that the 1-forms should be given by
$$ e_0^\ast = \sqrt{1 + 4 r^2} dr,\qquad e_1^\ast  = r d\phi,$$ because now it holds that $e_0^\ast\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4r^2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\right)=1$ and similarly $$e_i^\ast(e_j) = \delta_{ij}.$$
But now, if I pose the Cartan structure equations, I have
$$ de_0^\ast = 0,\quad de_1^\ast = dr\wedge d\phi.$$
Something must have gone wrong on the way, but I am a bit stuck where. Any help/idea is appreciated!
Thanks

Why is that wrong? Those differentials sit on one side of the structure equation and can be zero sometimes. What you have to do is to proceed setting up the structure equations and find the skew-symmetric $2\times 2$-matrix. Perhaps best to start with  a two-sphere for which you can check all your results (say the curvatures) by comparing them with well-known ones from more  traditional methods.

This is correct, although I am not thrilled with your notation. So you have $de_i^* = \sum \omega_{ij}\wedge e_j^*$, with $\omega_{ij} = -\omega_{ji}$. You should find that $\omega_{01} = \dfrac 1{\sqrt{1+4r^2}}d\phi$. Proceed.
You might find Section 3 of Chapter 3 of my (free) differential geometry text, linked in my profile, helpful. Also, look at a good text, like J. Clelland's From Frenet to Cartan: The Method of Moving Frames.

Thanks! That helps a lot. Then I was closer to it then I thought. However one thing, that surprises me is that shouldn't it be $$de_1^\ast = 1\cdot dr \wedge d\phi = \omega_{10}\wedge e_0^\ast = \omega_{01}\wedge {\sqrt{1+4 r^2}} dr $$? Then we should get
$$\omega_{10} =-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4 r^2}} d\phi,$$ resp $\omega_{01} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4 r^2}} d\phi.$
Thanks a lot!!

Yes, you’re right, of course. I made a hurried typo.
